# How to redirect to another page with muiltple results in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working in asp.net. In my application, if admin wants to see the list of users who have age from 20 to 30, he will give the range and will click on Search button. After clicking, admin will be redirected to another page which will show the list of users according to the age range. I want to show the result in gridview. The problem I am having is, I don't know how to pass multiple users to another page on button click so that there I can bind the grid with the result.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "select Profile_ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Name, Age, Occupation, Education, Number, Email,  City  from UserProfile where Age BETWEEN  " + from.Text + " AND " + to.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                       // here I have to save the result to pass to the following page
                       Response.Redirect("Users.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Rather than pass the list of users, can you pass the search term and use the search term to get the users on `Users.aspx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than fetching data inside button click function , pass the range as parameters to redirected page

Response.Redirect("Users.aspx?lower=20&upper=30");

and captured the parameter values on page load of this page using Request.QueryString(). Now use these captures parameters to get data,as u were doing earlier,inside,button click function and bind gridview here.

Comment: @user, it is normal (and recommended) that useful answers are upvoted (by clicking the up arrow), and the one that fully answered your question is marked as accepted (by clicking the tick under the arrows on ONE of the answers).  This way, you give credit to the person/people helping you, and show the community that your problem has been solved

Comment: yup I was doing that but It was forbidding me because I had to wait for 7 minutes